# Angulars $routeProvider does not route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, url-routing

I have a `$routeProvider` in my Angular JS application which won't load the template in the ng-view. 
I've set up `<html data-ng-app="myApp">` and `<section data-ng-view></section`.

It does neither load the template (doesn't even make an XHR), nor does it redirect on other paths (like `/#/foo/bar/foo/` and it doesn't throw an error.

This is my configuration:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myAppFilters'])
    .config [
        '$routeProvider',
        ($routeProvider) ->
            $routeProvider
                .when '/:year/:month',
                    templateUrl: 'partials/detail.html'
                    controller: DetailCntl
                .when '/:user/:year/:month',
                    templateUrl: 'partials/detail.html'
                    controller: DetailCntl
                .otherwise
                    redirectTo: '/'
    ]
```

**Edit:** Here's the compiled JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myAppFilters']).config([
    '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
      return $routeProvider.when('/:year/:month', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/detail.html',
        controller: DetailCntl
      }).when('/:user/:year/:month', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/detail.html',
        controller: DetailCntl
      }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
    }
  ]);
```

**Edit #2:** I found the solution by myself:
I had this line in my `factories.coffee` which overwrote the config:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).factory 'api', ($http, $q, $cacheFactory) ->
...
```

Now I have the config assigned to `@myApp` and am using `@myApp.factory 'api', ...` and it's working.

Comment: The config has typo of `[`, this should be `(`

Comment: @Chandermani Thank you, but that's fine. I added the compiled JS, the code above is CoffeeScript.

Comment: Do you see some error in browser console?

Comment: @Chandermani No, as I wrote, it doesn't throw any errors.

Comment: How have you included your scripts in you html. This may be a script ordering issue.

Comment: One more thing that you can try to pass controller as string value like `DetailCntl` if your controller is defined on the module.

Comment: `<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>` and `<script src="js/myApp.js"></script>`

Comment: The thing is: Even if I rename the controllers to anything not existing, it won't throw an error. It looks like it'd simply ignore the config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself: I had this line in my factories.coffee which overwrote the config:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).factory 'api', ($http, $q, $cacheFactory) ->
...
```

Now I have the config assigned to `@myApp` and am using `@myApp.factory 'api', ...` and it's working.

Thanks for your support.